# populate data from database when tab key is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery, ajax and php to retrieve data from database. I want to achieve a functionality i.e. When user inputs product code and press TAB Key the data should be filled in textarea. I'm new to ajax n php, I've checked my query in SQL it is working.. Please help me

**html**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-5 detectTab" name="product_code" />
<textarea class="form-control autogrow" id="container" name="desc" rows="3" cols="5" placeholder="Remarks" required></textarea>
```

**Script**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#product_code").keydown(function(e){
if(9 == e.keyCode){
       var postlink = 'loaddesc.php';
            $.post(postlink).done(function(data){
                if(data)
                    $("#container").val(data);
                else
                    $("#container").val('No Data Received');
            }
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

**loaddesc.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if($_POST['$product_code'] )
{
$product_code=$_POST['product_code'];
$sql=mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT concat(A.PRODUCT_CAT_NAME," - ", B.name," - ", C.PRODUCT_SERIAL_NO," - ",c.product_desc) Product_Details 
                        FROM dms_product_cat A, dms_product_type B, dms_products c WHERE A.product_cat_id = 1 AND B.product_cat_id = A.product_cat_id and B.type_id = c.product_type
and c.product_code = "$product_code"');
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    $data=$row['Product_Details'];
    echo $data;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query can not works because variables in single quote strings are not evaluated. 
Anyway it s a bad idea to build your request like this. There is a sql injection vulnerability in it.

You should read this:
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

**Logical Solution to your question**

> When user inputs product code and press TAB Key the data should be
>   filled in textarea.

- START
- input box where user will fill data and will press tab
- a javascript function call on pressing key
- check whether the key is "tab"
- jquery post method fire to server requesting data
- fetched data in success
- display the data in the required textarea
- DONE

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST AJAX</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- The input Box -->
    <input type="text" name="product_code" id="product_code" autofocus/>
    <!-- The Text Area -->
    <textarea id="container" name="desc" placeholder="Remarks"></textarea>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    // Will fire on any key press in input box
    $("#product_code").keydown(function(e){

        //alert(e.keyCode); // Remove the comment to check for keypress Code

        // KeyCode 9 is for TAB key
        if(9 == e.keyCode){
            // Sending via ajax to fetch data
            var postlink = ''; // Required Backend Script Handler
            $.post(postlink).done(function(data){
                // Handling the fetched data
                if(data)
                    $("#container").val(data); // Filling data in textarea
                else
                    $("#container").val('No Data Recieved'); // No data recieved
            }
        }
    })
})
</script>
</html>
```

> I believe your issue is settled now.

Thanks & Regards